# image retrieved from url does not fit properly into UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, tableview, nsdata, nsurl

I'm trying to download an image from an url and display into a cell (sample below):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
```

Somehow when I display into the cell, it covers the whole cell, bigger than my UIImageView.

But If I display the image locally like below:

```
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultProfile.png"]];
```

It fits perfectly into the UIImageView I set into the cell.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

use scaleToFit property of imageview